# How to use id_prefix with OpenSSL s_server

Tags: ssl, openssl, tls1.2

I'm not sure what argument do I have to pass to switch `-id_prefix` for [openssl s_server](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/s_server.html).

What I am trying to do is to run `openssl s_server` on one side, and `openssl s_client` on the other, and verify that `Session-ID` and `Master-Key` matches on both sides.

The problem is, that I only get to see the `Session-ID` and `Master-Key` on the client side. I'm not sure how to obtain them on the server side as well, so I can compare them.
`id_prefix` seems to be one option, but I don't see the prefix in the `Session-ID` on the client side.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I can see how you can check the Master-Key using `openssl s_server` and `openssl s_client`, but not the Session-ID; I'm not sure why.

Here's what I did.  First, I started a server running locally:

```
$ openssl s_server -accept 4433 -cert ./server.pem -tls1_2
```

Then, in a different terminal/window, I connected to that server:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:4433 -debug
```

In the server terminal, I saw the SSL session started:

```
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT
-----BEGIN SSL SESSION PARAMETERS-----
MFUCAQECAgMDBALAMAQABDDAOWXb47pESLXfWW1DYfaccOPGQcfgeaHW4sFP/avj
ejwVgvWNXGXy1vn6U3uLOeWhBgIEVqrm26IEAgIcIKQGBAQBAAAA
-----END SSL SESSION PARAMETERS-----
...
CIPHER is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
```

The key thing thing to notice here is that base64-encoded data for the SSL session parameters.  I copy and pasted that data into a separate file, *e.g.* `sess.pem`.

Then, I used `openssl sess_id` to decode that `sess.pem` file:

```
$ openssl sess_id -noout -text < ./sess.pem
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : C030
    Session-ID: 
    Session-ID-ctx: 01000000
    Master-Key:     9C921511052D3F212FF718704518FC526474D69FC26BC1165DBD203C6E221BB3A84686BC5D15A7BD9FA7BB72201A7276
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1454040610
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

Compare that Master-Key value with the one that the `openssl s_client` terminal shows (**note** that it's important to use the `-debug` command-line option for `openssl s_client` to see this):

```
...
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 1024 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID:     417D443BFD5702BEA974C5758FD65A0FC217B0FD9750C4CECF0915895C4E616D
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key:     9C921511052D3F212FF718704518FC526474D69FC26BC1165DBD203C6E221BB3A84686BC5D15A7BD9FA7BB72201A7276
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 7200 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    ....
```

So I'm not sure why the server output doesn't show the session ID generated, but you can at least use the above to compare the Master-Key values.  I experimented with using both the `-context` and `-id_prefix` command-line options for `openssl s_server`, *e.g.*:

```
$ openssl s_server -accept 4433 -context FOO -id_prefix BAR ...
```

but it did not substantially change the data, nor did it cause the Session-ID to be displayed by `openssl s_server`.

Hope this helps!